# How to Connect to Specific Zookeeper Clusters?

Tags: scala, hadoop, solr, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am implementing a Scala function which parses the JSON file and loads the data into HBase.It is working good on a local machine whose zookeeper servers are localhost.

Now for scaling purposes, I am trying to implement this on a Hadoop clusters with three specific zookeeper clusters node00,node01,solr.

I was wondering how to access the specific clusters through my code.Do I need to connect them beforehand as there is following error always.

```
    17/12/27 18:20:17 WARN zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting to reconnect

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Please get back to me on this

Edit1:

Thanks a lot for your response.
I couldn't check by the methods you suggested as I was not having sufficient permissions.
Following is the code which takes in the input JSON and parses to HBase.

```
    val input_base =""


val files = List("ffff")


for (collection_name <- files){
    val input_filename = input_base + collection_name + ".json"
    var col_name = collection_name
    var collection_Id = "1007"

    @transient val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
    @transient val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create(hadoopConf)
    conf.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)
    @transient val jobConfig: JobConf = new JobConf(conf, this.getClass)
    jobConfig.setOutputFormat(classOf[TableOutputFormat])
    jobConfig.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, tableName)

    sc.textFile(input_filename).map(l => parse_json(l,col_name,collection_Id)).saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConfig)

}
```

I need help in giving those nodes as parameters in my code.
The zookeeper quorum has solr2.dlrl,node02.dlrl,node00.dlrl as nodes and 2181 as port.
Please help me in ths

If I run the rowcounter function it is able to properly connect to the clusters

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.RowCounter ram
```

It is shown as follows:

```
    18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-696.6.3.el6.x86_64
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=cs5604f17_cta
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/cs5604f17_cta
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/cs5604f17_cta/ram/cmt/CMT/cs5604f17_cmt
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=solr2.dlrl:2181,node02.dlrl:2181,node00.dlrl:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=hconnection-0x524af2a60x0, quorum=solr2.dlrl:2181,node02.dlrl:2181,node00.dlrl:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server solr2.dlrl/10.0.0.125:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /10.0.0.127:54862, server: solr2.dlrl/10.0.0.125:2181
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server solr2.dlrl/10.0.0.125:2181, sessionid = 0x160aa7b7c311ea2, negotiated timeout = 60000
18/01/02 14:52:41 INFO util.RegionSizeCalculator: Calculating region sizes for table "ram-irma".
18/01/02 14:52:42 INFO client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing master protocol: MasterService
18/01/02 14:52:42 INFO client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation: Closing zookeeper sessionid=0x160aa7b7c311ea2
18/01/02 14:52:42 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x160aa7b7c311ea2 closed
18/01/02 14:52:42 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
18/01/02 14:52:42 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:12
18/01/02 14:52:42 INFO Configuration.deprecation: io.bytes.per.checksum is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.bytes-per-checksum
18/01/02 14:52:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1514688768112_0007
18/01/02 14:52:43 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1514688768112_0007
18/01/02 14:52:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://node02.dlrl:8088/proxy/application_1514688768112_0007/
18/01/02 14:52:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1514688768112_0007
18/01/02 14:52:48 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1514688768112_0007 running in uber mode : false
```

Comment: As this is quite possibly a network issue, could you verify that you are able to connect tho those servers from your computer using some other Zookeeper client such as  [zkCli](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperStarted.html#N10091)? If you can't - investigate the network/firewalls. And if you can - you must show us more of your code.

Comment: `for server null`...? Please show your existing code / configuration

Comment: Can you add more information ? Make sure that `telnet zkNode 2181` is working from the machine you are working from

Comment: I have updated the post.Please help me in this.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated the post.Plz help me in this.

Comment: `The url to track the job`... Upload logs from it